# What happens to Berry curvature under time reversal symmetries, in band structures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, time-reversal-symmetry, berry-pancharatnam-phase

First let we have a system with a periodic potential such that we can apply Bloch theorem to it.
$|\psi_{n,k}>=e^{ikr}|u_{n,k}>,$ is our eigen function n and k are band indice and cyrstal momentum.
$\mathcal{H}|\psi_{n,k}>=E_{n,k}|\psi_{n,k}>.$ describes our system.

If we have time reversal symmetry than,$[\mathcal{H},\mathcal{T}]=0$

$\mathcal{T}|n,k>=\int dr\mathcal{T}|r><r|n,k>^{*}$
which implies

$\mathcal{T}\psi(r)_{n,k}=\psi^{*}(r)_{n,k}.$

Now let $T_{R}$ is translation operator,
$T_{R}(a)\mathcal{T}\psi(r)_{n,k}\overset{}{=}\mathcal{T}T_{R}\psi(r)_{n,k}=\mathcal{T}e^{-ika}\psi(r)_{n,k}=e^{ika}\mathcal{T}\psi(r)_{n,k}$

and

$T_{R}(a)\psi(r)_{n,k}=e^{-ika}\psi(r)_{n,k},$

so $\mathcal{T}\psi(r)_{n,k}=\psi^{*}(r)_{n,k}$
  is eigenfunction of $T_{R}$
  with $e^{ika}$
  eigenvalue, while $\psi(r)_{n,k}$
  is another one with eigenvalue $e^{-ika}$
 .

Hence
$\mathcal{T}\psi(r)_{n,k}=\psi^{*}(r)_{n,k}=\psi(r)_{n,-k}$.

Now we can analyse the beery curvature under time reversal

Berry Curvature is given as $ \mathcal{F}=-i\epsilon_{ij}\int\partial_{ki}u_{n,k}(r)^{*}\partial_{k}u_{n,kj}(r)dr$
So if I apply the TRS operator on Bloch waves as I derived;
$\mathcal{TF}(k)=-i\epsilon_{ij}\int\partial_{ki}\mathcal{T}u_{n,k}(r)^{*}\partial_{kj}\mathcal{T}u_{n,k}(r)dr\\=-i\epsilon_{ij}\int\partial_{ki}u_{n,-k}(r)^{*}\partial_{kj}u_{n,-k}(r)dr\\=\mathcal{F}(-k)$

But in some litreture they find $\mathcal{TF}(k)=\mathcal{-F}(-k).
 $

So where is my mistake?

Comment: When you apply $\mathcal{T}$ to $\mathcal{F}$, why the imaginary unit $i$ in front of $\epsilon_{ij}$ does not change sign?

Comment: because applying time reversal to F  means calculating F with time reversed states, it   does not mean applying T to F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRS of Berry curvature,

$\mathcal{F}^{\alpha}(k)=-\mathcal{F}^{\beta}(-k).$
 if there is a time reversal symmetry $\alpha$
  and $\beta$
  shows the normal and time reversed frames.

***proof:***

$\mathcal{F}=-i\epsilon_{ij}<\partial_{ki}u_{n}(k)|\partial_{kj}u_{n}(k)>$

$\mathcal{F}^{\alpha}(-k) =-i\epsilon_{ij}<\partial_{ki}u_{n}^{\alpha}(-k)|\partial_{kj}u_{n}^{\alpha}(-k)>$

$=-i\epsilon_{ij}<\partial_{kj}\mathcal{T}u_{n}^{\alpha}(-k)|\partial_{ki}\mathcal{T}u_{n}^{\alpha}(-k)>$

$=i\epsilon_{ij}<\partial_{ki}\mathcal{T}u_{n}^{\alpha}(-k)|\partial_{kj}\mathcal{T}u_{n}^{\alpha}(-k)>$

Now let $\mathcal{T}u(-k)^{\alpha}=u^{\beta}(k)$
 , so we can write

$\mathcal{F}^{\beta}(k) =-i\epsilon_{ij}<\partial_{ki}u_{n}^{\beta}(k)|\partial_{kj}u_{n}^{\beta}(k)>$
    $=-i\epsilon_{ij}<\partial_{ki}\mathcal{T}u_{n}^{\alpha}(-k)|\partial_{kj}\mathcal{T}u_{n}^{\alpha}(-k)>$

$=-\mathcal{F}^{\alpha}(-k)$